# How to replace a chain of the same characters of unkown length from a string to a unique occurrence or it?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following string in my DB, in a column we will name 'info', in a table we can call 'conversation':

```
Hello, I''''''''''''''''m Brian and I''''m looking for the kitchen
```

I would like to know if it's possible to replace the `''''''` to a single occurrence of itself in PostgreSQL.

So:

```
Hello, I'm Brian and I'm looking for the kitchen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` for that:

```
select regexp_replace(info, '''+', '''', 'g')
from conversation;
```

The regular expression looks a bit weird due to the escaping of the single quotes, but it essentially is: `'+` which means "at least one single quoted followed by any number of single quotes" and the replacement values (third parameter) is just one single quote.

Online example: https://rextester.com/HGWDZ41975

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!